# Xamarin Forms use Gelf4Net to send logs to graylog

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, log4net

I have created console application (.NetCore), add gelf4Net library, implement solution, load configuration and make it work to send logs to graylog. Logs are present on console, in file and on server.

Now I need to do the same in Xamarin Forms application (right now only for android). I have added class library, install gelf4net library. I have added config.xml to Xamarin Forms project as embedded resource. I get content of config and save it in external storage as xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="GelfHttpAppender" type="Gelf4Net.Appender.GelfHttpAppender, Gelf4Net">
            <url value="http://yourserver.com/gelf" />
            <threshold value ="INFO" />
            <layout type="Gelf4Net.Layout.GelfLayout, Gelf4Net">
                <param name="AdditionalFields" value="app:HttpAppender,Environment:LocalDevelop,Level:%level,HostName:tp" />
                <param name="Facility" value="TP" />
                <param name="IncludeLocationInformation" value="false" />
                <param name="SendTimeStampAsString" value="false"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="LoggerNetCoreEngine.CustomAppenders.ConsoleAppender_JSON, KC_LoggerNetCoreEngine">
            <threshold value ="ERROR" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <appender-ref ref="GelfHttpAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Then I get file info and load configuration:

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(assembly);
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(configPath);
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(logRepository, fileInfo);
```

Configuration is being loaded successfully and any changes that I made in config file, they are taking effect on application behaviour.

From debug console:

```
04-28 17:52:48.831 D/Mono    ( 4627): Loading reference 2 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/se.company.nameApp/files/.__override__/Gelf4Net.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Gelf4Net.HttpAppender, Version=1.0.0.18, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b04c12492d51401e22
04-28 17:52:48.831 D/Mono    ( 4627): Assembly Ref addref Gelf4Net[0xebbccfe0] -> Gelf4Net.HttpAppender[0xebbcd0a0]: 2
04-28 17:52:48.831 D/Mono    ( 4627): Requesting loading reference 2 (of 8) of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/se.company.nameApp/files/.__override__/Gelf4Net.HttpAppender.dll
04-28 17:52:48.831 D/Mono    ( 4627): Loading reference 2 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/se.company.nameApp/files/.__override__/Gelf4Net.HttpAppender.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1af1a2a
04-28 17:52:48.831 D/Mono    ( 4627): Assembly Ref addref Gelf4Net.HttpAppender[0xebbcd0a0] -> log4net[0xebbcd340]: 3
04-28 17:52:48.832 D/Mono    ( 4627): Requesting loading reference 3 (of 8) of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/se.company.nameApp/files/.__override__/Gelf4Net.HttpAppender.dll
04-28 17:52:48.832 D/Mono    ( 4627): Loading reference 3 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/se.company.nameApp/files/.__override__/Gelf4Net.HttpAppender.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7fwf11d50a3a
04-28 17:52:48.831 D/Mono    ( 4627): Loading reference 2 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/se.company.nameApp/files/.__override__/Gelf4Net.HttpAppender.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral04-28 17:52:48.832 W/Mono    ( 4627): The request to load the assembly System.Net.Http v4.1.1.0 was remapped to v4.0.0.0
04-28 17:52:48.832 D/Mono    ( 4627): Assembly Ref addref Gelf4Net.HttpAppender[0xebbcd0a0] -> System.Net.Http[0xcbb05140]: 3
```

Finally, logs are present only into console (I didnt put code here, but it is working well). Has anyone any idea how to make it able to work also via http, because nothing comes to server?